# CAShapeLayer problems - not drawing in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, cashapelayer

I'm trying to use `CAShapeLayer` to draw a filled circle on each `UITableViewCell` that has a certain property (if a bool property is true). The reason I use `CAShapeLayer` is so I can animate it later.

When the tableView gets rendered out initially it works fine. However, when cells are added or removed things go wrong, badly wrong! The circle gets drawn in wrong cells and sometimes outside (below) the cells. I have no idea what is going wrong. Since setting `clipsToBounds` on the cells, it seems to have stopped the circles being drawn outside of the cells however this still doesn't solve the problem of some being drawn/some not.

The following code (supposedly) draws a filled circle. It is present in my custom `UITableViewCell` class:

```
    let radius = 15
    self.circleLayerForAnimation = CAShapeLayer()

    self.circleLayerForAnimation!.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(2*radius), CGFloat(2*radius)), cornerRadius: CGFloat(radius)).CGPath
    self.circleLayerForAnimation!.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(CGRectMake(self.frame.width - 20.0 - 30.0, 15.0, 30.0, 30.0)) - CGFloat(radius), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-CGFloat(radius))
    self.circleLayerForAnimation!.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    self.circleLayerForAnimation!.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    self.circleLayerForAnimation!.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    self.circleLayerForAnimation!.lineWidth = 1

    self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(self.circleLayerForAnimation)
```

In my table view controller I have the following code to draw/remove circles in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
    if (shouldShowCircle == true) {
        if (cell!.circleLayerForAnimation == nil) {
            cell!.fillCircle() // code above
        }  
    } else {
        if (cell!.circleLayerForAnimation != nil) {
            cell!.circleLayerForAnimation!.removeFromSuperlayer()
            cell!.circleLayerForAnimation = nil
        }  
    }
```

Can someone please help out here as this has been driving me mad the past few hours!

Thanks

Comment: do you have a screenshot?
I suppose this is a problem when the cell is reused.

Answer (score 1):

Try running animation when cell is displayed.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: yes, I think this would have solved my problem - my guess is the cell's frame changes during the display sequence. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My problem lay with the frames. Replacing:

```
self.circleLayerForAnimation!.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(CGRectMake(self.frame.width - 20.0 - 30.0, 15.0, 30.0, 30.0)) - CGFloat(radius), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-CGFloat(radius))
```

with:

```
self.circleLayerForAnimation!.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.width - 20.0 - 30.0, 15.0, 30.0, 30.0)) - CGFloat(radius), CGRectGetMidY(self.contentView.frame)-CGFloat(radius))
```

generates results as expected.